# Magento: how to get URLs for categories in different stores?

Tags: php, magento

I have several different storeviews in different languages, which are accessible through domain.com/de, domain.com/fr etc.

The same categories are used in these storeviews (e.g., domain.com/de/mensfashion, domain.com/fr/mensfashion -- most category names are not translated but that's besides the question).

Now, I want to generate a sitemap with rel-alternates in there:

```
<loc>"http://domain.com/de/mensfashion"</loc>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="http://domain.com/fr/mensfashion"/>
...
```

So, for a category I need to be able to loop through all stores and get the URL for that store.
Getting the URL is easy enough through

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($de_store_id);
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)->getUrl();
```

but then no matter what I try to change to the next $fr_store_id, I keep getting the same URL for the initial set store....

I tried (any combination and order of) the following:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($fr_store_id);

Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId($fr_store_id)->load($category_id);

$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($fr_store_id);
```

but none of this seems to actually do anything, I keep getting the german result back...

I suspect it has something to do with the model that is loaded only once, ie some cache issue, and I am quite aware that in generating a sitemap with hundreds of links with 10 alternatives each, it's not a good idea anyway to go to the database for each individual link. 
Any help would be much appreciated!

PS if the only efficient way to do it is in SQL that's appreciated as well... but curious to know whether there is an easy solution in code.

Comment: Can you try Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setRequestPath('')->setStoreId($fr_store_id)->load($category_id);

Comment: that doesn't compile... it doesn't recognise setStoreId?